# R Shiny - Editing a Datatable in a script that has already been written

Tags: r, shiny

I have a an existing R script that takes data from our company's data source and creates a graph. The data is put in a long dataframe that is then multiplied with another similar dataframe that has trend factors in it to create low, mid, and high scenarios. This dataframe product is then graphed out to create a graph showing depreciation over time and in the next few years.

I would like to make this trend dataframe editable using R Shiny so that external users of the app can adjust the scenarios how they would like. Any suggestions on how to best approach this?

Here is the dataframe (Tibble) of trend factors that I am using if that would help. (I know there is a better way to create this dataframe, but I am unsure how.)

```
typefactors <- tibble(
  "Year" = c(year(today()), year(today()), year(today()),year(today()), year(today()), year(today()),
             year(today()) + 1, year(today()) + 1, year(today()) + 1, year(today()) + 1, year(today()) + 1, year(today()) + 1, 
             year(today()) + 2, year(today()) + 2, year(today()) + 2, year(today()) + 2, year(today()) + 2, year(today()) + 2, 
             year(today()) + 3, year(today()) + 3, year(today()) + 3, year(today()) + 3, year(today()) + 3, year(today()) + 3),
  "Projected" = c("Expected", "Expected", "High", "High", "Low", "Low",
                  "Expected", "Expected", "High", "High", "Low", "Low",
                  "Expected", "Expected", "High", "High", "Low", "Low",
                  "Expected", "Expected", "High", "High", "Low", "Low"),
  "Type" = c("Car", "Truck", "Car", "Truck","Car", "Truck",
             "Car", "Truck", "Car", "Truck","Car", "Truck",
             "Car", "Truck", "Car", "Truck","Car", "Truck",
             "Car", "Truck", "Car", "Truck","Car", "Truck"),
  "Exp" = c(
    #Current Year  Expected      High        Low 
    0.975,  0.96,   0.98,   0.98,   0.96,   0.92,
    #Year + 1      Expected      High        Low 
    0.96,   0.96,   1.01,   0.98,   0.94,   0.95,
    #Year + 2      Expected      High        Low 
    0.99,   0.98,   1.02,   1.00,   0.98,   0.97,
    #Year + 3      Expected      High        Low 
    1.00,   0.98,   1.03,   1.02,   1.00,   0.98)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can (*per se*) do this. You should however be aware that editing data is not exactly the strength of Shiny.

You can create an input element by calling `textInput`. You can call `textInput` either within the `ui` part of `shinyApp` or dynamically within a call to `insertUI`. I'd suggest starting with the earlier. However you do it, you then need to define a variable for each input (the first argument of `textInput`. Within any code you write, you can access these variables. Assume now you have `y0exp`, `y0low`, `y1high` etc.

In order to update, you can either listen for changes to the text input or (maybe a simpler start) to the click of an "update" button. So, within the `server` part of `shinyApp`, you need to call `observeEvent` to actually listen to that click.

Now you're almost there: you need to transfer `y0exp` and friends into the data frame. In your case, that would probably be something like `typefactors$Exp[2] <- y0exp` (within the function you pass into `observeEvent`). Most probably, you'll also have to re-draw any graphs you have w/in the click event handler.

I would note here that having a basically flat list with the first six values being the current year, the next six values being the next year, etc. is indeed a little unfortunate. I'd consider creating a `data.frame(year=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0), tpe=c('car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'truck'), exp=c(0.98, 0.98, 1.0, 1.02, 0.98), ...` (or maybe I'm already in the wrong col) and then using something like `merge` to bind it.

An addition to all that, you might think about persisting the inputs. If I was the user, I'd hate updating 12+ values every time I open the app. You can do all of that, you should just remember that you're signing up for a little bit more work as Shiny is great at presenting and only average on editing.

If you want to see a complete example for how to do it: I did some write-up on this a couple weeks back (incl. a Github Repo). You find this here: https://sebastianrothbucher.github.io/datascience/r/visualization/shiny/couchdb/2017/10/14/test-drive-shiny-r-rstudio-couchdb.html and here: https://github.com/sebastianrothbucher/ShinyCouch/blob/master/app.R